# useContext is not displaying the updated state (when data is retrieved from firebase in useEffect hook in global file) in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-context, use-context

I am using context api to have a global state of products, for this I have ProductsContext.js

I have an empty state of array defined like this in ProductsContext.js

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
```

In the same file (ProductsContext.js) I am using useEffect to retrive all the products from firebase and then updating the products state. Below is all the code of ProductsContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { db } from '../Config/Config'

export const ProductsContext = createContext();

export const ProductsContextProvider = (props) => {
    // console.log(props);
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('use effect');
        const prevProducts = products;
        db.collection('Products').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
            changes.forEach(change => {
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                    prevProducts.push({
                        ProductID: change.doc.id,
                        ProductName: change.doc.data().ProductName,
                        ProductDescription: change.doc.data().ProductDescription,
                        ProductPrice: change.doc.data().ProductPrice,
                        ProductImg: change.doc.data().ProductImg
                    })
                }
                // console.log(prevProducts);
                setProducts(prevProducts);
                console.log(products); // I am able to see the products in console
            })
        })
    })

    return (
        <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products: [...products] }}>
            {props.children}
        </ProductsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

My problem is Home.js is my child component and I am using useContext in this file but it is not returning the updated state but only returning an empty array

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { ProductsContext } from '../Global/ProductsContext'

export const Home = () => {
    const { products } = useContext(ProductsContext);
    console.log(products); // empty array
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

this is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ProductsContextProvider } from './Global/ProductsContext'
import { Home } from './Components/Home'

export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ProductsContextProvider>
                <Home />
            </ProductsContextProvider>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: `setProducts(prevProducts);` is setting local state... where are you storing this to your context?... since you created context with blank `export const ProductsContext = createContext();` and are not updating the context... this is why you get blank when you do `const { products } = useContext(ProductsContext);`

Comment: How do I update the context?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502664/

Comment: sir check my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your state is an object (or an array, but that's technically also an object), you must avoid mutating it.

In your code, you are mutating your `products` array, by calling `push(...)` on the original array instead of creating a copy of it.

Setting the state with a mutated array does not trigger an update because React compares the reference of the next array with the previous array and determines it to be equal.

To solve this, create a copy of the array and update the state with that:

```js
const prevProducts = [...products];
```

Comment: sir, doing this, I have got products in my Home.js but I am kind of stuck in an awkward situation, I don't know how to define this but it is kind of a loop in console. I have now just infinite number of products now and its keep increasing

Comment: Check my below answer please

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but when I changed my functional component (ProductsContext.js) to class based component with the same approach, it is somehow working and I am able to get the products in my child components. Here is the code

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import { db } from '../Config/Config'

export const ProductsContext = createContext();

export class ProductsContextProvider extends React.Component {

    state = {
        products: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const prevProducts = this.state.products;
        db.collection('Products').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
            changes.forEach(change => {
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                    prevProducts.push({
                        ProductID: change.doc.id,
                        ProductName: change.doc.data().ProductName,
                        ProductDescription: change.doc.data().ProductDescription,
                        ProductPrice: change.doc.data().ProductPrice,
                        ProductImg: change.doc.data().ProductImg
                    })
                }
                // console.log(prevProducts);
                this.setState({
                    products: prevProducts
                })
                // console.log(this.state.products);
            })
        })

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products: [...this.state.products] }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ProductsContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```