# In React component lifecycle methods, `this.context` is an empty Object

Tags: reactjs

Why is `this.context` an empty object, in this React component lifecycle methods?

The context has the correct value in the `Consumer` for that context. Only the `this.context` API is failing.

```jsx
const LoremContext = React.createContext({
    lorem: "ipsum",
})


class MenuItem extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(
            "In MenuItem.componentDidMount, this.context is:",
            this.context)
    }

    render() {
        console.log(
            "In MenuItem.render, this.context is:",
            this.context)
        return ( <LoremContext.Consumer>{
            (lorem) => {
                console.log("In LoremContext.Consumer, lorem is:", lorem)
                return (
                    <li>
                        { `Eat ${this.props.dish} at ${lorem}` }
                    </li>
                )
            }
        }</LoremContext.Consumer> )
    }
}

MenuItem.contextType = LoremContext

class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        …
    }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <LoremContext.Provider value={ this.props.world.lorem }>
                <section className="app">
                    <Menu menuItems={ [ … ] } />
                <p>Fusce varius id arcu egestas sodales</p>
            </section>
        </LoremContext.Provider>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Application world={ { lorem: "consecteur" } } />,
    document.getElementById('app-container'),
)
```

This is using React 16.4, so it makes use of the [documented context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (introduced in React 16.3).

According to that documented API, the above code should get access to the context (defined in the return value from [`React.createContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)) in two ways:

- The `LoremContext.Consumer` component receives the context value passed by the `LoremContext.Provider`.

  The consumer then provides that context value as an argument to the function within that component. In this case, `lorem` is the argument that receives the context value.
- The `this.context` property receives (because of the [declared `MenuItem.contextType` class property](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype)) the context value, inside the “lifecycle methods”.

Only one of those is working for me.

- The `LoremContext.Consumer` API is getting and passing the context value correctly. The `console.log` output is:

```
  In LoremContext.Consumer, lorem is: consecteur
```

- The `this.context` is not getting the correct value, instead it gets an empty Object. The `console.log` output is:

```
  In MenuItem.render, context is: Object {  }
  In MenuItem.componentDidMount, context is: Object {  }
```

So the consumer is receiving the correct value, but `this.context` is not. Why the difference? How can I get the correct value received at `this.context`?

Comment: The similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49809884/70157 doesn't answer this (the answers seem to assume the API won't work as documented, and provide alternative workarounds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.context` was introduced in React 16.6 that you see can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13728)

Before this version, on [16.4](https://5b90c17ac9659241e7f4c938--reactjs.netlify.com/docs/context.html#accessing-context-in-lifecycle-methods), that you are using, accessing context inside React Lifecycles can be achieved:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // ThemeContext value is this.props.theme
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Previous ThemeContext value is prevProps.theme
    // New ThemeContext value is this.props.theme
  }

  render() {
    const {theme, children} = this.props;
    return (
      <button className={theme || 'light'}>
        {children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default props => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {theme => <Button {...props} theme={theme} />}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);
```

See [docs for more information](https://5b90c17ac9659241e7f4c938--reactjs.netlify.com/docs/context.html#accessing-context-in-lifecycle-methods)

Comment: “this.context was introduced in React 16.6” — Well, crap. It'd be clearer if they *said* that in the documentation, instead of making a lot of noise about all this being new in 16.3. Thank you.

Comment: they could use a new label somewhere. But tough luck, this was added like a day or two ago

Comment: @bignose I don't see any inconsistencies here. React documentation covers the last version, which is 16.6 as of now. Context API is 16.3. context+contextType is 16.6. If you need to know where specific feature comes from, this can be figured out from a changelog or https://reactjs.org/blog/

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the context in a separate file and then importing it.  That worked for me.  When `createContext` was called in the same file where the `<MyContext.Provider>` tag was used, the consumers only saw an empty object.  When I moved `createContext` to a separate file, the consumers saw the expected values.  This applies to both methods of consuming - `<MyContext.Consumer>` and `MyClass.contextType/this.context`.

I'm afraid I can't explain *why* this works, but I found the solution in [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13969).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly without this part in the target component it is empty.

```
static contextType = ThemeContext; // assign the correct context
```

before created like

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html