# How do I wrap React-Native Alert so it will use the colorScheme from a context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Similar to [Access React Context outside of render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809884/access-react-context-outside-of-render-function) but I am looking to add a way of extending `Alert.alert` so that it will use the color scheme from theme.

```
  const { colorScheme } = useTheming();
...
    Alert.alert(t`logout`, "Are you sure you want to logout?", [
      {
        text: "No",
      },
      {
        style: "destructive",
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: logoutAsync,
      },
    ], {
      userInterfaceStyle: colorScheme
    });
```

I just want it so that the color scheme does not need to be added in.

I started with

```
import { Alert as RNAlert } from 'react-native'
export class Alert implements RNAlert {
  static alert(...) {
     // how do I get the data from the context?
  }
  static prompt(...) {
  }
}
```

Comment: `userInterfaceStyle` is an iOS only thing, so if you want to same alert functionality on both iOS and android, then you will want to make your own Alert component (which will be an absolutely position modal). While more work, it will give you total control over how customizable the modal/alert can be

Comment: Also is it absolutely necessary for you to use a class component?

Comment: I started to work out a custom alert demo but I was using hooks instead of class components https://snack.expo.dev/P6Smzk4FS

Comment: If the alert prop accepted a buttons array where each item was a button title and an onPress function you could easily add buttons to the modal and get it to look really similar to the alert api

Comment: And if you used `onLayout`  to get the view y and height, that calls the alert, you use layout.y + layout.height to position the modal directly under the View

Comment: The problem is to use it in a non-component scenario form like the `Alert.alert` API itself.  `Alert` isn't a class component, it's just an API.  I wanted to wrap a non-React component API to use hooks which I don't think is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer yet since I don't wrap the `Alert` object, but this is the closest I have gotten.

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Alert as RNAlert, AlertButton, AlertOptions } from 'react-native';
import { useTheming } from "./ThemeContext";

export function useAlert(): RNAlert {
    const { colorScheme } = useTheming();
    const alert = useCallback((title: string, message?: string, buttons?: AlertButton[], options?: AlertOptions): void => {
        const newOptions = { userInterfaceStyle: options?.userInterfaceStyle ?? colorScheme, ...options }
        RNAlert.alert(title, message, buttons, newOptions);
    }, [colorScheme])
    return { alert, prompt: RNAlert.prompt };
}
```

The key thing to watch out for is when you're using it with `useCallback` you have to remember to add the new alert to the dependency list.

```
  const { alert } = useAlert();
  ...
  const handleLogout = useCallback(() => {
    alert(t`logout`, "Are you sure you want to logout?", [
      {
        text: "No",
      },
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: logoutAsync,
      },
    ]);
  }, [logoutAsync, alert]);
```